# Sort an element and put it in a variable

Tags: recursion, common-lisp

I have fowling task:
Write a recursive function SORT-LIST which, from a list of any number of "apples" and "peas", sorts out the "apples" and stores them in an optional variable and at the end returns the contents of this optional variable.

I have no idea how to fix ist. That's my beginning. Maybe there is someone who could help me. Thanks a lot!!

```
(defun sort-list (x l)
  (cond ((null l) nil))
  ((equal (first l) x)
   (cons (first l) (sort-list x (rest l))))
  ((sort-list x (rest l))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The name is misleading. It is not `sort` but actually a `filter`.

```
(defun applep (x)
  "something looking whether x is an apple or not")

(defun my-filter (pred l &optionals (acc '()))
  (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
        ((funcall pred (car l)) (my-filter pred (cdr l) (cons (car l) acc)))
        (t (my-filter pred (cdr l) acc))))
```

Which is in-built in lisps - so even without defining it, you could run:

```
(filter #'applep l)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! For me it looks very difficult. We do not use nreverse and funcall. But anyways thank you!

Comment: You can use `reverse` instead of `nreverse`. One uses `nreverse` in this case only because it is faster and has less memory footprint.

Comment: `(funcall func ...)` means that one applies `func` on the given arguments. Instead of `funcall` one could also use `apply` in this manner: `(apply func (list ...))`.

Comment: otherwise you have to put your condition (a `pred` - a predicate function - contains usually just conditions which return a boolean value. In this case - is the argument an apple or not. You could place the test literatlly there.

Comment: Alright! Thanks for the detailed explanation! I actually have one more question: what would the function look like if the amount of the content of the optional variable is to be output?

Comment: what you mean with that? what you mean with "amount of the content"? The length of `acc`? Just change `(nreverse acc)` to `(length acc)`.